I'm trying to make A * pathfinding algorithm however I'm stuck as it doesn't work as expected gets stuck on walls and so on I don't know what's wrong
I tried to filter unsearched but the same nodes keep on being add and keeps on going back to the same positions
I expect it to find the correct path to the target
but the enemy just gets stuck on a wall
also the input is just for testing purposes as I wanted to use a while but it would get stuck in infinite loops as well as the start position when the path is not found





using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Experimental.AI;
using static UnityEngine.UIElements.UxmlAttributeDescription;
 
public class Pathfiding : MonoBehaviour
{
 
    public LayerMask wall;
    public Transform Start_, Target_;
    List<Node> Serched = new List<Node>();
    List<Node> Unserched = new List<Node>();
    List<Vector3> Path = new List<Vector3>();
    Vector3 StartPos;
    Vector3 NeighbourStart;
    Vector3 ConstStart;
    private Vector3[] directions;
    bool NoWall;
    Vector3 worldPos;
    Vector3 worldPos2;
    float LowestGcost;
    float LowestGcost2;
    float LowestHcost;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
 
    public KeyCode exitKey = KeyCode.Escape;
 
 
    void Start()
    {
 
        directions = new Vector3[]
        {
              new Vector3(0, 0, 1) , // Forward
            new Vector3(0, 0, -1),  // Backward
            new Vector3(-1, 0, 0),  // Left
            new Vector3(1, 0, 0),   // Right
            new Vector3(-1, 0, 1),  // Forward-Left
            new Vector3(1, 0, 1),   // Forward-Right
            new Vector3(-1, 0, -1), // Backward-Left
            new Vector3(1, 0, -1)   // Backward-Right
 
 
        };
        StartPos = Start_.position;
        ConstStart = Start_.position;
        Node newNode = new Node(0, Vector3.Distance(StartPos, Target_.position), Vector3.Distance(StartPos, Target_.position), StartPos, 'h');
        Serched.Add(newNode);
    //    LowestFcost();
 
 
    }
 
 
 
 
    private void Update()
    {
        LowestFcost();
    }
 
    void LowestFcost()
    {
 
    //    while (StartPos != Target_.position)
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.K))
        {
 
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                // Calculate the world position by adding the direction vector
                worldPos = StartPos + directions[i];
                Start_.position = worldPos;
                NoWall = Physics.CheckSphere(worldPos, 0.5f, wall);
 
                if (NoWall == false)
                {
                    // Declare Gcost, Hcost, and Fcost variables
                    float Gcost = 0;
                    float Hcost = Vector3.Distance(worldPos, Target_.position);
                    float Fcost;
                    char Direction;
                    // Determine Gcost and Fcost based on the index
                    if (i < 4)
                    {
                        Direction = 'h';
                        Gcost += 10;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Direction = 'v';
                        Gcost +=14;
                    }
 
                    Fcost = Gcost + Hcost;
 
                    // Create a new Node with these values
                    Node newNode = new Node(Gcost, Hcost, Fcost, worldPos, Direction);
 
                    // Check if a node with the same properties already exists
                    bool nodeExists = false;
                    for (int j = 0; j < Unserched.Count; j++)
                    {
                        if (Unserched[j].Gcost == newNode.Gcost &&
                            Unserched[j].Hcost == newNode.Hcost &&
                            Unserched[j].Fcost == newNode.Fcost &&
                            Unserched[j].WorldPos == newNode.WorldPos &&
                            Unserched[j].direction == newNode.direction)
                        {
                            nodeExists = true;
                            break;  // Exit the loop early if a match is found
                        }
                    }
 
                    // Add the node only if it doesn't already exist
                    if (nodeExists == false)
                    {
                        Unserched.Add(newNode);
                    }
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
                }
 
            }
            Unserched.Sort();
 
 
            float index3 = (int)LowestHcost;
            index3 = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < Unserched.Count; i++)
            {
 
                if (Unserched[0].Fcost == Unserched[i].Fcost)
                {
                    if (Unserched[i].Hcost > index3)
                    {
                        index3 = i;
                    }
 
 
                }
            }
 
 
            Serched.Add(Unserched[(int)index3]);
            Unserched.Remove(Unserched[(int)index3]);
            StartPos = Serched[Serched.Count-1].WorldPos;
            UpdateUnSerched();
        }
        if (StartPos == Target_.position)
        {
            while (StartPos != Start_.position)
            {
                Serched.Reverse();
                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                {
 
                    worldPos2 = StartPos + directions[i];
                    for (int j = 0; j < Serched.Count; j++)
                    {
 
                        if (j == 0)
                        {
                            LowestGcost2 = Serched[0].Gcost;
                        }
 
                        if (worldPos == Serched[j].WorldPos)
                        {
 
                            if (LowestGcost2 < Serched[j].Gcost)
                            {
 
                                LowestGcost2 = j;
                            }
 
 
                        }
 
                    }
 
                }
                int index2 = (int)LowestGcost2;
                Path.Add(Serched[index2].WorldPos);
 
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < Path.Count; i++)
            {
 
                Start_.position = Path[i];
            }
 
        }
        void UpdateUnSerched()
        {
            NeighbourStart = Unserched[0].WorldPos;
            int actual = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < Unserched.Count; i++)
            {
                while (NeighbourStart != ConstStart)
                {
 
 
 
                    for (int j = 0; j < Serched.Count; j++)
                    {
 
                        for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++)
                        {
                            // Calculate the world position by adding the direction vector
                            worldPos = NeighbourStart + directions[k];//look around
 
 
                            NoWall = Physics.CheckSphere(worldPos, 0.5f, wall);
 
                            if (NoWall == false)
                            {
                                if (k == 0)
                                {
                                    LowestGcost = Serched[0].Gcost;
                                }
 
                                if (worldPos == Serched[j].WorldPos)
                                {
 
                                    if (Serched[j].Gcost < Serched[(int)LowestGcost].Gcost)
                                    {
 
                                        LowestGcost = j;
                                    }
 
 
                                }
 
                            }
                        }
                    }
 
                    int index = (int)LowestGcost;
                    if (Serched[index].direction == 'h')
                    {
                        actual += 10;
 
                    }
                    if (Serched[index].direction == 'v')
                    {
                        actual += 14;
 
                    }
 
                    NeighbourStart = Serched[index].WorldPos;
                }
                if (actual != Unserched[i].Gcost)
                {
                    Unserched[i].Gcost = actual;
 
                }
 
 
 
            }
 
        }
 
 
    }
}
using System;
using UnityEngine;
 
public class Node : IComparable<Node>
{
    public float Gcost;
    public float Hcost;
    public float Fcost;
    public Vector3 WorldPos;
    public Char direction;
 
    public Node(float _Gcost, float _Hcost, float _Fcost, Vector3 _WorldPos, char _direction)
    {
        Gcost = _Gcost;
        Hcost = _Hcost;
        Fcost = _Fcost;
        WorldPos = _WorldPos;
        direction = _direction;
    }
 
    // Implement the CompareTo method as required by IComparable<Node>
    public int CompareTo(Node other)
    {
        if (other == null) return 1;
 
        // Compare Fcost values to sort in ascending order
        return Fcost.CompareTo(other.Fcost);
    }
}


And what happened when you debugged it?
